# Simulate input for DualShock4 Controller

Tags: python, input

I'm trying to simulate button presses for my PS4 Controller to essentially create a macro. This macro would continuously tap a button when the trigger is held.

How would I approach this? I know you can read inputs from the controller such as how long the a button has been pressed for, using the approxeng library.

Comment: This will be pretty platform-specific, so what operating system are you using?

Comment: I'm using a Raspberry Pi so Raspbian I believe.